# How can I dual boot Ubuntu 13.04 with Windows 7 Home Premium?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, 13.04

I have a nice impression to Ubuntu before and I want to dual boot it with my Windows OS. (I'm a total newbie in this field :D )

I have downloaded the latest Universal USB Installer and the Ubuntu 13.04 ISO (the 32-bit version). Then, I've burned the installer to my USB. My laptop is Samsung X420 and I can't create another partition for Ubuntu because these built-in partitions:

- Unnamed [healthy(Recovery Partition)] = 15GB, 0GB used
- Unnamed [healthy(System, Active, Primary Partition)] = 100MB, 72MB used
- (C:) [healthy(Boot, Page File, Crash Dump, Primary Partition)] = 141.49GB, 68.5GB
  used
- (G:) [healthy(Primary Partition)] = 141.50GB, 118.49GB used

After I restarted my laptop, there was no boot menu for Ubuntu or anything installation guide. It simply restarted to Windows 7. I checked again my USB and I found the WUBI App. Then, I ran it as administrator and chose the "Reboot Now." but nothing happened. As usual, goes directly to Windows.

I haven't formatted my USB because its already FAT32 and I'm afraid to loose important files stored there.

I hope someone will throw light in me regarding this issue. T___T
Feel free to reply/contact if you're still confused. (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: is it necessary to have a partition? -Jian

Comment: Yes it is necessary to have a separate partition for Ubuntu. Ubuntu uses partitions in the ext4 format that has features NTFS or FAT32 does not have. It is also a good idea to have a `swap` partition for Ubuntu. WUBI has some bugs and is deprecated as it does not work with newer computers with UEFI (a replacement for BIOS). So yes, you will need to delete one of the partitions and make space for new ones. The default install process will create the partitions it needs in the empty (unallocated) space.

Answer (score 0):

You've had a faulty installation i guess. It'd be easier to come up with a solution to this if you could explain the steps you've taken to install Ubuntu on your system, alongwith screenshots of the install process (to show which drive was chosen etc), additionally, it needs to be told as to which drive you installed Ubuntu on.

Standard procedure for installing Ubuntu on a laptop which has Windows pre-installed is as follows-

A)You can choose the install Ubuntu alongside Windows option and then the bootloader does all the work that needs to be done and you're left with minimum tinkering.

B)You can choose the 'Something Else' option, there you'll have to choose one of your hard disks, create a swap area (say 500mb) and a primary partition at the '/' mount point. doing so would lead to your disk being formatted for the necessary operations and then Ubuntu would be installed on your system.

The steps that you followed, were they any different? Plus, are you on a 34 or 64 bit system?

Comment: i'm running on a 32bit system. I made the live USB and then I simply restarted. I didn't made another partition. Uhm, is that ok? I can't merge the two unnamed partitions T.T .

Comment: did you choose the install alongside windows option?

Comment: and, you can edit your partitions using gparted, it's there in the live usb.